# Python: Tkinter GUI User Input saved to a txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter

Please forgive me that I am relatively new/noob to Python. 
Currently I have a test.txt file that my project reads. It is basically in a list. 
I want to be able to create a GUI that enables user to enter the information and save it to that test.txt. I also want to be able to click on the "Show" button and displays the current content of test.txt in my GUI.

***Update:***
Here is my code so far. The save function will save the tkinter entry to my txt file. That has worked fine. My problem is with the "Show" button. I cant use the file.readlines() and get a string of data and put them back to my tkinter GUI. They don't seem to insert into my GUI and I am getting errors **ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**

```
from Tkinter import *

def save():
    text = e1.get() + "\n"+e2.get() + "\n"+e3.get() 
    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(text)

def show():
    with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
        f.readlines()
    e1.get(f.seek(0))
    e2.get(f.seek(1))
    e3.get(f.seek(2))


master = Tk(className = "ABM Inputs")

Label(master, text="RNG Seed").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Manipulator Exists 1=yes, 0=no").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Number of Investors").grid(row=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(master, text='Save', command=save).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any tkinter code for this problem? if so, can you post it.

Comment: Your first step is to work through a tkinter tutorial so that you understand the fundamentals. Then, try to create a GUI that meets your needs. When you get stuck _with a specific problem_, come back here and ask about that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is basically a text editor. Have a look in [here](http://knowpapa.com/text-editor/). The try to use the functions supplied to build your app. I imagine you know about creating buttons and basic tkinter.